# Storing a list of strings to a HDF5 Dataset from Python

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I am trying to store a variable length list of string to a HDF5 Dataset. The code for this is

```
import h5py
h5File=h5py.File('xxx.h5','w')
strList=['asas','asas','asas']  
h5File.create_dataset('xxx',(len(strList),1),'S10',strList)
h5File.flush() 
h5File.Close()
```

I am getting an error stating that "TypeError: No conversion path for dtype: dtype('&lt U3')"
where the &lt means actual less than symbol
How can I solve this problem.

Comment: For starters, you have a typo on `create_dataset`. Can you give the exact code you're using, especially where `strList` is coming from?

Comment: sorry about the typo, I am trying to serialize a pandas data frame to a HDF5 file so I have to create a header that contains the names of the all columns so I extracted the column names in a list and trying to write it to a HDF5 dataset.

Comment: except for the typo above code emulates exactly similar situation

Comment: You should probably edit your question and fix the typo.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You're reading in Unicode strings, but specifying your datatype as ASCII. According to [the h5py wiki](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/wiki/Unicode-Manifesto#creating-datasets-from-input-python-data), h5py does not currently support this conversion.

You'll need to encode the strings in a format h5py handles:

```
asciiList = [n.encode("ascii", "ignore") for n in strList]
h5File.create_dataset('xxx', (len(asciiList),1),'S10', asciiList)
```

Note: not everything encoded in UTF-8 can be encoded in ASCII!

Comment: What's the proper way to re-extract these strings from the hdf5 file (in python3)?

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix ASCII is also valid UTF-8, but you can use `ascii.decode('utf-8')` if you need `str` type.

Note: my answer will drop non-ASCII characters. If you preserved them with `encode('unicode_escape')`, then you need `decode('unicode_escape')` to convert things back.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix. To re-extract the code :   stringlist=np.array(f['xxx'])
vals=[str(el).strip('[]').strip('\'') for el in stringlist.astype(str)]

Answer (score 21):

From https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/special.html:

> In HDF5, data in VL format is stored as arbitrary-length vectors of a
> base type. In particular, strings are stored C-style in
> null-terminated buffers. NumPy has no native mechanism to support
> this. Unfortunately, this is the de facto standard for representing
> strings in the HDF5 C API, and in many HDF5 applications.
>
> Thankfully, NumPy has a generic pointer type in the form of the
> “object” (“O”) dtype. In h5py, variable-length strings are mapped to
> object arrays. A small amount of metadata attached to an “O” dtype
> tells h5py that its contents should be converted to VL strings when
> stored in the file.
>
> Existing VL strings can be read and written to with no additional
> effort; Python strings and fixed-length NumPy strings can be
> auto-converted to VL data and stored.

Example

```
In [27]: dt = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=str)

In [28]: dset = h5File.create_dataset('vlen_str', (100,), dtype=dt)

In [29]: dset[0] = 'the change of water into water vapour'

In [30]: dset[0]
Out[30]: 'the change of water into water vapour'
```

Comment: if I have a list of string `['foo','bar']`,  how could I assign the list value to the dataset?

Comment: Minor correction: *"String data in HDF5 datasets is read as bytes by default: `bytes` objects for variable-length strings, or numpy bytes arrays (`'S'` dtypes) for fixed-length strings."* (source: https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/strings.html#strings) So the output for line 30 is actually `b'the change of water into water vapour'`.

Answer (score 6):

I am in a similar situation wanting to store column names of dataframe as a dataset in hdf5 file. Assuming df.columns is what I want to store, I found the following works:

```
h5File = h5py.File('my_file.h5','w')
h5File['col_names'] = df.columns.values.astype('S')
```

This assumes the column names are 'simple' strings that can be encoded in ASCII.