# Storing a list of strings to a HDF5 Dataset from Python using VL format

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I expected the following code to work, but it doesn't.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

with h5py.File('file.hdf5','w') as hf:
    dt = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=str)
    feature_names = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])
    hf.create_dataset('feature names', data=feature_names, dtype=dt)
```

I get the error message `TypeError: No conversion path for dtype: dtype('<U1')`. The following code does work, but using a for loop to copy the data seems a bit clunky to me. **Is there a more straightforward way to do this?** I would prefer to be able to pass the sequence of strings directly into the `create_dataset` function.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

with h5py.File('file.hdf5','w') as hf:
    dt = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=str)
    feature_names = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])
    ds = hf.create_dataset('feature names', (len(feature_names),), dtype=dt)

    for i in range(len(feature_names)):
        ds[i] = feature_names[i]
```

Note: My question follows from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43935389/663299) to [Storing a list of strings to a HDF5 Dataset from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220513/storing-a-list-of-strings-to-a-hdf5-dataset-from-python), but I don't consider it a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Define "straightforward."  Your loop that works is about as "straightforward" as it gets.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I was hoping that there was a Python type that I could use for my sequence/list/vector of variable-length strings, that could directly be used by `hp5y`.

Comment: Does `ds[:] = feature_names` work?  Or `data=feature_names.astype(object)`?

Comment: @hpaulj `ds[:] = feature_names` works, but your second option doesn't. If you want to turn that into an answer, I'll vote it up. Also, I'll accept it unless someone comes up with a way to pass the list into the `create_dataset` function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You almost did it, the missing detail was to pass `dtype` to `np.array`:

```
import h5py                                                                                                                                                                                                
import numpy as np            

with h5py.File('file.hdf5','w') as hf: 
     dt = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=str) 
     feature_names = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=dt) 
     hf.create_dataset('feature names', data=feature_names)
```

PS: It looks like a bug for me - `create_dataset` ignores the given `dtype` and don't apply it to the given `data`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, saves me several hours!